# Save Appointment task dows not fire the Grids focus Event

Tags: windows-phone

I am working on saving Appointments But if I do A `(new SaveAppointmentTask()).Show()`

Then it doesnot fire the Grids OnFocus event when doing a save or a Cancel. Please Direct me to a proper step of detecting that the Xaml page is In Focus ie the current Page.

Here's The XAML and the CS

```
<Grid OnFocus="Grid_Focus"></Grid>
```

Cs

```
private void OnFocus(args args){
//if I put a break point here then it does not hit
}
```

Please look into it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heres the reason why . Phone tasks donot open in the same app rather they open in a new window .when u save or cancel they navigate back to your app which is already activated and running in background. In such case the method OnNavigateTo is fired. Let me share a link of the event go through it you will understand.

[On navigated to](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.page.onnavigatedto%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)

Comment: thanks i tested and yes it is hitting the break point. wonder why the app navigates away. if you have any idea then please share.